# How to select all links inside of nav element

Tags: javascript

I have a page with many links but I want to use js select all the links inside of the nav tag and assign them to a variable named navigationLinks. Is there a way to do this without assigning a class to all the links. `

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the js:

```
let navigationLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have control over the html of it?  If so you could add an id or class to the nav and use the .children(); method ( https://api.jquery.com/children/ ) You could do it without an id too and just grab the tag... but if you ever put another nav element on your page it could get messy.  If you have control over the html, no matter what method you use I'd recommend using an id or class something as opposed to just referencing the tag.

Comment: navigationLinks.getElementsByTagName('a');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let navigationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
```

But remember it's a NodeList object.

Comment: Thanks KubaJastrz. This worked without having to add another class.

Answer (score 0):

Your given JavaScript:

```
let navigationLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
```

is wrong, use `[0]` after `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')` to select the first navigation-element.

Use this code to assign a class `my-class` to every `<a>` link inside `nav`

```js
let navigationLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

var ul = navigationLinks.children[0];
var ulChilds = ul.children;
function insertClass() {
    for (var x=0;x < ulChilds.length;x++) {
        ulChilds[x].className += ' my-class';
    }
}
button.onclick = insertClass;
```

```css
.my-class {
    background: yellow; /*Just testing class*/
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<button>Add my-class</button>
```

Hope, you needed this.

Answer (score 0):

```
let navElement = document.getElementsByTagName('NAV');

let navigationLinks = navElement[0].getElementsByTagName('A');
```

if you are having multiple nav tags you may need to loop it accordingly